# Extracting fields from a javascript section of an HTML document into tables? Geographic coordinates

Tags: javascript, json, excel, web-scraping, vba

I have an HTML document that contains geographic information within a block of Javascript. It is the source code from this web page: https://energy.ehawaii.gov/epd/public/energy-projects-map.html

This can be viewed as a map and also as a list.

What I want to achieve is to have that list in Excel, but with a field for "Latitude" and a field for "Longitude". The Google Maps marker specifies the `LatLng` in the Javascript.

How can I use something like VB to process the source code of the HTML file, and organize into a table that has the following fields/columns:

- Description (from the `<a ... title="such and such">`)
- Technology (from `<p>Technology: Solar</p>` for example)
- Latitude (from `google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);`
- Longtitude (from the same code line as latitude, but using the second variable)?

All help appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Try this VBScript solution based on XMLHTTP requests. Just copy the code below, paste to text file, save it as `.vbs` and run it. Script hasn't been optimized, all requests are not async, so it takes about 40 seconds on my PC to get all data.

```
Option Explicit
Dim arrCells(), arrList, arrTmp, sRespHeaders, sRespText, arrSetHeaders, i, j, iTotal, oApp, oWB, oWS, oOutput

' Create output window
Output oOutput

' Get cookies
oOutput.write "Get cookies"
XmlHttpGet "https://energy.ehawaii.gov/epd/public/energy-projects-map.html", Array(), sRespHeaders, sRespText
ParseResponse "^Set-(Cookie): ([\S]*?=[\S]*?);[\s\S]*?$", sRespHeaders, arrSetHeaders

' Get project list
oOutput.write "Get project list"
arrList = Array()
XmlHttpGet "https://energy.ehawaii.gov/epd/public/energy-projects-list.json?sEcho=2&iColumns=5&sColumns=&iDisplayStart=1&iDisplayLength=0&mDataProp_0=0&mDataProp_1=1&mDataProp_2=2&mDataProp_3=3&mDataProp_4=4&sSearch=&bRegex=false&sSearch_0=&bRegex_0=false&bSearchable_0=true&sSearch_1=&bRegex_1=false&bSearchable_1=true&sSearch_2=&bRegex_2=false&bSearchable_2=true&sSearch_3=&bRegex_3=false&bSearchable_3=true&sSearch_4=&bRegex_4=false&bSearchable_4=true&iSortCol_0=0&sSortDir_0=asc&iSortingCols=1&bSortable_0=true&bSortable_1=true&bSortable_2=true&bSortable_3=true&bSortable_4=true", arrSetHeaders, "", sRespText
ParseProjects sRespText, arrList, iTotal
oOutput.write "Get project list: " & (UBound(arrList) + 1) & " of " & iTotal

' Rearrange to 2-dimensional array, get LatLng
ReDim arrCells(UBound(arrList), 8) ' Name, Technology, Island, Capacity, Location, RID, Type, Lat, Lng
For i = 0 To UBound(arrList)
    For j = 0 To 6
        arrCells(i, j) = arrList(i)(j)
    Next
    oOutput.write "Get LatLng: " & (i + 1) & " of " & iTotal
    arrTmp = RequestLatLng(arrList(i)(5))
    arrCells(i, 7) = arrTmp(0)
    arrCells(i, 8) = arrTmp(1)
Next

' Create Excel worksheet, output data
oOutput.write "Export to Excel"
Set oApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
oApp.Visible = True
Set oWB = oApp.Workbooks.Add(-4167) ' xlWBATWorksheet
Set oWS = oWB.Worksheets(1)
oWS.Range(oWS.Cells(1, 1), oWS.Cells(UBound(arrCells) + 1, 9)).Value = arrCells
oWS.Columns.AutoFit
oWB.Saved = True
oOutput.write "Completed"

Sub XmlHttpGet(sQuery, arrSetHeaders, sRespHeaders, sRespText)
    Dim arrHeader
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
        .SetOption 2, 13056 ' SXH_SERVER_CERT_IGNORE_ALL_SERVER_ERRORS
        .Open "GET", sQuery, False
        For Each arrHeader In arrSetHeaders
            .SetRequestHeader arrHeader(0), arrHeader(1)
        Next
        .Send ""
        sRespHeaders = .GetAllResponseHeaders
        sRespText = .ResponseText
    End With
End Sub

Sub ParseResponse(sPattern, sResponse, aData)
    Dim oMatch, aTmp, sSubMatch
    aData = Array()
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .Pattern = sPattern
        For Each oMatch In .Execute(sResponse)
            If oMatch.SubMatches.Count = 1 Then
                PushItem aData, oMatch.SubMatches(0)
            Else
                aTmp = Array()
                For Each sSubMatch In oMatch.SubMatches
                    PushItem aTmp, sSubMatch
                Next
                PushItem aData, aTmp
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub

Sub PushItem(aList, vItem)
    ReDim Preserve aList(UBound(aList) + 1)
    aList(UBound(aList)) = vItem
End Sub

Sub ParseProjects(sJson, arrProj, iTotalRecords)
    Dim i, q
    With CreateObject("htmlfile")
        With .parentwindow
            .execscript ";", "jscript"
            .eval ("json = " & sJson & ";")
            iTotalRecords = CInt(.json.iTotalRecords)
            Do While .json.aaData.Length
                ReDim Preserve arrProj(UBound(arrProj) + 1)
                With .json.aaData.Shift()
                    arrProj(UBound(arrProj)) = Array(.Shift(), .Shift(), .Shift(), .Shift(), .Shift(), .Shift(), .Shift())
                End With
            Loop
        End With
    End With
End Sub

Function RequestLatLng(sRid)
    Dim sRespText, arrTmp, sTmp
    XmlHttpGet "https://energy.ehawaii.gov/epd/public/energy-project-details.html?rid=" & sRid, Array(), "", sRespText
    arrTmp = Split(sRespText, "google.maps.LatLng(")
    If UBound(arrTmp) >= 1 Then
        sTmp = arrTmp(1)
        arrTmp = Split(sTmp, "),")
        If UBound(arrTmp) >= 1 Then
            RequestLatLng = Split(arrTmp(0), ", ")
            Exit Function
        End If
    End If
    RequestLatLng = Array("#", "#")
End Function

Sub Output(oWnd)
    Set oWnd = ShowWindow("energy.ehawaii.gov", "data:image/png;base64,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", 354, 118)
End Sub

Function ShowWindow(sTitle, sBG, iWidth, iHeight)
    Set ShowWindow = CreateWindow()
    With ShowWindow
        With .document
            .title = sTitle
            .getElementsByTagName("head")(0).appendChild .createElement("style")
            .styleSheets(0).cssText = "* {font: 8pt tahoma; margin: 5px;}"
            .body.style.background = "buttonface"
            .body.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat"
            .body.style.backgroundImage = "url(" & sBG & ")"
            .body.innerHTML = ""
        End With
        .resizeTo .screen.availWidth, .screen.availHeight
        .resizeTo iWidth + .screen.availWidth - .document.body.offsetWidth, iHeight + .screen.availHeight - .document.body.offsetHeight
        .moveTo CInt((.screen.availWidth - iWidth) / 2), CInt((.screen.availHeight - iHeight) / 2)
        .execScript "var handlers, thunks = {body_onunload: function() {handlers.WSHQuit()}};"
        Execute "Class clsHandlers: Public Sub WSHQuit(): WScript.Quit: End Sub: End Class"
        Set .handlers = New clsHandlers
        Set .document.body.onunload = .thunks.body_onunload
        .execScript "var write = function(t) {document.body.innerHTML = t};"
    End With
End Function

Function CreateWindow()
    ' source http://forum.script-coding.com/viewtopic.php?pid=75356#p75356
    Dim sSignature, oShellWnd, oProc
    On Error Resume Next
    sSignature = Left(CreateObject("Scriptlet.TypeLib").Guid, 38)
    Do
        Set oProc = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec("mshta ""about:<head><script>moveTo(-32000,-32000);document.title=' '</script><hta:application id=app border=thick minimizebutton=no maximizebutton=no scroll=no showintaskbar=yes contextmenu=no selection=no innerborder=no icon=""""/><object id='shell' classid='clsid:8856F961-340A-11D0-A96B-00C04FD705A2'><param name=RegisterAsBrowser value=1></object><script>shell.putproperty('" & sSignature & "',document.parentWindow);</script></head>""")
        Do
            If oProc.Status > 0 Then Exit Do
            For Each oShellWnd In CreateObject("Shell.Application").Windows
                Set CreateWindow = oShellWnd.GetProperty(sSignature)
                If Err.Number = 0 Then Exit Function
                Err.Clear
            Next
        Loop
    Loop
End Function
```

Comment: Some improvements regarding [WSH VBS GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47111556/2165759) solution.

Answer (score 0):

Sure it's possible. But here at StackOverflow we solve issues not write code for existing solutions.

However I would start by analyzing this link:
[https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/ViewportInfoService.GetViewportInfo?1m6&1m2&1d12.821947129167481&2d-175.06889349440217&2m2&1d28.109653321636404&2d-140.54826660818202&2u7&4spl-PL&5e0&6sm%40290000000&7b0&8e0&9b0&callback=*xdc*._48sez1&token=119313](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/ViewportInfoService.GetViewportInfo?1m6&1m2&1d12.821947129167481&2d-175.06889349440217&2m2&1d28.109653321636404&2d-140.54826660818202&2u7&4spl-PL&5e0&6sm%40290000000&7b0&8e0&9b0&callback=_xdc_._48sez1&token=119313)

From it you will get the JSON with the lats and longs. You can use many solutions out there. I personally made a simple [Scrape HTML Add-In](http://blog.tkacprow.pl/excel-tools/excel-scrape-html-add/) to Excel myself. All you need to learn is regular expressions.