# VBScript MsgBox during processing

Tags: vbscript, msgbox

Every month I have to create small statistics for my boss. I took this over from an colleague who retired. I wrote some VBScripts, to make the Excel sheets look similar, displaying status is false. Now I want to add a small window, which states the text "In progress" while my script is running. When it's finished the box shall disappear.

I was looking on the Internet for help, and there are some interesting codes, but I can't imagine, that it's not possible with `MsgBox`.

Comment: What you want is not possible with `MsgBox`. At least not with `MsgBox` alone. There are some workarounds, though. You could for instance `Exec` a second script that would display the message, or create a custom dialog using the Internet Explorer COM object.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22545156/2165759) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28377215/2165759) examples.

Comment: Ok, I how would the script look like, if I would do so?

Comment: How do you run the VBScript? Using the command line? If so, you could change the title of the command prompt window before and after the script runs, using the c:\dir>title TITLE GOES HERE command

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I start this VBscript via double klick on the .vbs file. Another possibility?